# Injecting a custom element in HTML5 then retrieving its value using XPath comes back blank

Tags: html, xpath, custom-element

I'm injecting an XML string generated from a web service, then trying to use XPath to query the attribute values using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>tox-js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------
    // tox element
    class Tox extends HTMLElement
        {
        constructor(url)
            {
            super();
            fetch(url)
                .then((response)=>
                    {
                    console.log("status: "+response.status);
                    return response.text();
                    })
                .then((text)=>
                    {
                    console.log("text: "+text);
                    try
                        {
                        var dp = new DOMParser();
                        var xmlDOM = dp.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
                        this.appendChild(xmlDOM.documentElement);
                        return true;
                        }
                    catch(err)
                        {
                        console.log("err: "+err.message);
                        return false;
                        }
                    })
                .then((ok)=>
                    {
                    if (ok)
                        {
                        try
                            {
                            var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
                            var txt = xpe.evaluate("//tox-js/example/@timestamp",document,null,XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,null);
                            console.log("//tox-js/example/@timestamp: "+txt.stringValue);
                            txt = xpe.evaluate("//tox-js/example/@feedback",document,null,XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,null);
                            console.log("//tox-js/example/@feedback: "+txt.stringValue);
                            }
                        catch(err)
                            {
                            console.log("err: "+err.message);
                            }
                        }
                    else
                        console.log("not ok");
                    }
                    );
            }
        }
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------
    // register our element with the DOM
    customElements.define('tox-js',Tox);
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------
    // create an instance and add it to the body
    document.body.appendChild(new Tox('http://localhost:8080/tox/example.test.formatted?in_mask=YYYYMMDD'));
    // -----------------------------------------------
    //
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result has the custom element injected.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <script>...</script>
        <tox-js>
            <example timestamp="20180103142036" feedback="ok">20190103</example>
        </tox-js>
    </body>
<html>
```

The console log confirms the return status and XML, but the result of the XPath is blank.

```
[Log] status: 200 (toxElement3.html, line 20)
[Log] text: <example timestamp="20190103142036" feedback="ok">20190103</example> (toxElement3.html, line 25)
[Log] //tox-js/example/@timestamp:  (toxElement3.html, line 47)
[Log] //tox-js/example/@feedback:  (toxElement3.html, line 49)
```

Where have I gone wrong?  This should not be a timing issue since I'm using `.then` to wait for the previous step.

Comment: Works in Firefox version 64, not in Chrome version 71, nor Safari version 12.

Comment: Can confirm that in Chrome it doesn't work, but works in Firefox. Also tried to use `$x(xpath)` in Chrome - it doesn't see the appended node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it is related to the namespaces.
The following XPath works for me:

```
//tox-js/*[local-name()='example']/@timestamp
```

Check this answer:
[XPath Doesn't Work in Dynamic HTML-Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109226/xpath-doesnt-work-in-dynamic-html-document)

Also you can use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) or [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to create element from text as described here: [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro/35385518#35385518)

In this case your XPath will work as expected.

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                var text = `<example timestamp="20180103142036" feedback="ok">20190103</example>`;
                var el = document.getElementsByTagName('tox-js')[0];
                el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', text);

                var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
                var txt = xpe.evaluate("//tox-js/example/@timestamp",document,null,XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,null);
                console.log(`//tox-js/example/@timestamp: ${txt.stringValue}`);
            });
        </script>
        <tox-js>
        </tox-js>
    </body>
<html>
```

P.S. I can't explain why the problem happens when using `DOMParser`. Maybe there are different namespaces for `document` and `DOMParser`. So if somebody has more details, feel free to extend the answer.

From the provided example...

```
var dp = new DOMParser();
var xmlDOM = dp.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
this.appendChild(xmlDOM.documentElement);
```

...becomes...

```
this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', text);
```

Comment: I edited in the only code change I had to do to make it work.  The XPath works in without any changes.

Comment: Good to hear it helped. Perhaps `DOMParser` has different implementations across browsers.